# Loading QImage from memory using OpenimageIO

Tags: python, qt, qimage

I'm trying to load QImage from memory. PyOpenimageIO gives me pixels in python array: array('f',[r1,g1,b1,r2,g2,b2]).
Using this function:

```
img = QtGui.QImage(pixels,spec.width, spec.height, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
```

or

```
img = QtGui.QImage(pixels.buffer_info()[0],spec.width, spec.height, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
```

gives me wrong result, like this:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6325775/nodes/images/out.png

setPixel() gives correct result, but very slow. Taking and filling char* from img.constBits() just a little bit faster.
How to load QImage from memory of python array?

Comment: I don't think there is a faster way. Python arrays are far different from QImage's internal formats, so some sort of conversion is unavoidable. You need to use `QImage::bits` or `QImage::scanLine` and fill data manually.